# How to upload Two images at a time on two different columns in Node.js/Sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Error: EMAXBUFFER: An upstream (`imagefile1`) timed out before it was plugged into a receiver. It was 
 still unused after waiting 4500ms. You can configure this timeout by changing the `maxTimeToBuffer` 
 option.Note that this error might be occurring due to an earlier file upload that is finally timing out 
 after an unrelated server error.

### My code:

```
        var uploaded = await sails.uploadOne(req.file('imagefile'));
        var oldPath = uploaded.fd;
        var filename = oldPath.split('\\')[oldPath.split('\\').length - 1];
        filename = filename.split('/')[filename.split('/').length - 1];
        var newPath = require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/images/' + filename);
        fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
        })
        reportdata.IDPhoto = filename;

        var uploaded1 = await sails.uploadOne(req.file('imagefile1'));
        var oldPath = uploaded1.fd;
        var filename = oldPath.split('\\')[oldPath.split('\\').length - 1];
        filename = filename.split('/')[filename.split('/').length - 1];
        var newPath = require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/images/' + filename);
        fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function (err) {
        })
        reportdata.ProfilePhoto = filename;
```

I also tried Skipper for this code still EMAXBUFFER Error occurs

Comment: i get the answer my answer is as below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var reportdata = {
        city: req.body.city,
        pincode: req.body.pincode,
        WorkExperience: req.body.WorkExperience,
      };

        //// FIRST IMAGE UPLOAD FOR IDPhoto 

            var upload= req.file('imagefile').upload({
                dirname: '../../assets/images/'

            }, async function data(error, uploadedFiles1) {

                var oldPath = JSON.stringify(uploadedFiles1);

            var filename = oldPath.split('\\')[oldPath.split('\\').length - 1];
            var vals = filename.split('"')[0];

            reportdata.IDPhoto = vals;    //// IDPhoto Bind with reportdata which 
                                          //// is declare above

        })

       //////  SECOND IMAGE UPLOAD FOR ProfilePhoto ///////

            var uploade= req.file('imagefiles').upload({
                dirname: '../../assets/images/'

            }, async function data(error, uploadedFiles2) {

                var oldPath = JSON.stringify(uploadedFiles2);

            var filename = oldPath.split('\\')[oldPath.split('\\').length - 1];
            var vals = filename.split('"')[0];

          reportdata.ProfilePhoto = vals;//// ProfilePhoto Bind with reportdata which 
                                         //// is declare above

         var reportdata2 = await TABLENAME.create( reportdata);

            })  //// Both images will upload at a time and image URL will stores in 
                 ////Database Table in Two different Columns by CREATE Query
```